# Monads return empty type: return ()

Tags: haskell

```
type InterpreterMonad = ErrorT String ((StateT (Stack EnvEval)) IO)


argsToContext :: [DefArg] -> [CallArg] -> InterpreterMonad ()
argsToContext xs ys = argsToContext' xs ys Map.empty where
    argsToContext' ((ArgForDefinition t name):xs) ((ArgForCall e):ys) m = get >>= \contextStack -> (argsToContext' xs ys (Map.insert name e m ))
    argsToContext' [] [] m = get >>= \contextStack -> (put (push contextStack m)) >>= \_ -> return ()


data DefArg =
   ArgForDefinition Type VarName   
data CallArg =
   ArgForCall Evaluable
```

Hi,

I've got a problem with understanding above piece of Haskell code

Especially, I cannot understand how does it `return ()` and why it is placed here.

Please explain.

Comment: It looks like it's just ignoring the result of the previous operation i.e. converting `m a` to `m ()`. Although `put` should return `m ()` anyway so you might be able to simply remove it.

Comment: Even in a context where you need to change `m a` to `m ()` you should probably use the badly-named `void` function which does just that or `() <$`. Either of those will be faster for certain functors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` in Haskell does not mean what it means in imperative languages like C or Java. In fact its really the wrong name, but we are stuck with it for historical reasons. Better names would be "pure" or "wrap", meaning that it takes a pure value and wraps it up into the monadic context.

The `()` type is known as "unit". Its not actually empty because it has one value, also called `()` (hence the name). However it is sort-of empty because you use it when you don't want to convey any information: there is only one value, so it needs zero bits to represent it. (There is a "Void" type available for when you really don't want it to have any values).

So `return ()` means that this monadic action wraps a unit up in the monadic context. In effect its a no-op: do nothing and return no information.

In this case its being used in the case where the arguments are two empty lists. `argsToContext'` has the job of pairing up the `DefArg` list with the `CallArg` list. The first definition takes the head of each list, does its thing with them, and then calls itself with the tails of each list. When the tails are both empty it calls the second version which puts the resulting context on top of the context stack. If the two lists are of different length then it will throw an exception because neither pattern matches. If its your code then you ought to put in a defensive case, partly to help you debug, partly to show that you actually thought about the case, and partly to stop the compiler nagging you about it.

The 'context' in this case is the interpreter's variables, which are held in the `Map`. Hence the only effect of `argsToContext'` is to add these pairs to the context and then return a 'Unit' value. The `InterpreterMonad` is the monadic type, and the return value has the type `InterpreterMonad ()`, meaning that no information is returned, it just has side effects within the monadic context.

In fact I don't think you need the `return ()` here because `put` already has type `m ()` for whatever monad you are in. So just delete the `>>= \_ -> return ()` and I think it will work fine.